# Syncing HTML5 Vidoes Between Devices

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, video.js

So I am using video.js as my video player on my website, but was curious if there was a way (either using video.js or another video player) to be able to sync a video between all devices on the website?

For example, if Person A, Person B and Person C is viewing this video on my website, it would sync their video up so they are at the same time, and if either of them pauses then all three people see their video pause? A lot like Netflix Party / Youtube Party for videos. I am quite new to JS

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to set and read the current time of a video in JavaScript with [HTMLMediaElement.currentTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime). You can also [play](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play)/[pause](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/pause) and check if its playing with either [the paused attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/paused) or the [pause/play](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#events) events.

You will need some form of backend to keep track of when all of this happens and to relay the appropriate time/events to everyone watching which is outside the scope of basic DOM JS (though there are JS based backends if that's your thing).

You'll probably need some form of live two-way connection like a [websocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

Comment: I am planning on using websockets, but my question is is there a way to have a 'master' client connected to the websocket? If Person A is watching a video and is 30 seconds in, and Person B joins, I want to send the video.currentTime() to the websocket to then be relayed back to the HTML pages, would video.currentTime() send 30 seconds or 0 seconds (Person B's video time) so I can sync the two videos up

Comment: My knowledge of websockets is limited but i'd imagine you could designate a specific websocket connection as the "master", only reading events from it and only sending events to all other clients

Comment: Hmm yeah, I am thinking of doing that my issue is there is difficulty in sending parameters from the video player when it is in one JS file, sending it to the websocket in a meaningful way and then sending that back to the new user who joins.

Comment: video.js has its own API for getting and setting elements of the video such as current time and play/pause. https://docs.videojs.com/docs/api/player.html

Comment: Hi, yeah I read through those, except when my video player is either in the HTML file or a JS file, then my websocket is in server/index.js file, I can't pull the videoplayer time for some reason, when I try to use the get method I get an 'Object object'

Comment: i'd ask a more specific question about just that (or google for it). websockets is outside the scope of my knowledge.